# Best practice to find if a coordinate is in a given polyline?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, mkoverlay, google-polyline

For a navigation app, i need to detect when the user deviated from a given driving path(represented as a list of coordinates), so what i want to do is whenever i get a new location update for the user, ill check if this location is in the path.
is that too complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a similar problem I create a path with CGPath and then test if a point is in the path. By controlling the path width you can the amount of deviation rather easily.

Here is example code, the point to test cones from a touch event:

```
- (void)createPath {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(   path, nil, 400, 300);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 500, 300);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 500, 400);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 400, 400);
    self.pathRef   = path;

    CGContextRef context = [self createOffscreenContext];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.pathWidth);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, self.pathRef);    
}

- (CGContextRef)createOffscreenContext {
    CFMutableDataRef empty = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
    CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(empty);
    self.offscreenContext = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, NULL, NULL);
    CGDataConsumerRelease(consumer);
    CFRelease(empty);

    return self.offscreenContext;
}

// Optional, not needed for the test to work
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.colorRef);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.pathWidth);

    CGContextAddPath(context, self.pathRef);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    BOOL isPointInPath = CGContextPathContainsPoint(self.offscreenContext, touchPoint, kCGPathStroke);

    NSLog(@"pip: %d, x: %3.0f, y: %3.0f", isPointInPath, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried to look at the CGPath class and I'm not sure how to create one from an array of coordinates, and how can i control the path width. can you show me how to do that please?

Comment: wow thanks that is very helpful! can use explain the part of creating the offScreenContext, why do i need it? to draw the path?

Comment: If you are happy with displaying on screen you do not need an offScreenContext, in my case it allows me to have a different width for hit detection (but not in this example).

Comment: I use CloudMade maps API to get routing info (distance, duration) for driving from A to B. The CloudMade automatically draw the result path on the map, it also give me an array of the path points. So i don't need to draw the path, but i do need the ability to check if the user current location is in this path. From your example i understood how to create the CGPath from the array of points, i still didn't understand the offScreenContext, is it used just for controlling the path width? and what is kCGPathStroke parameter?

Comment: Since you don't need to draw the path on the screen all you need is the offscreen path.

Comment: OK thanks, one more question, to be more accurate the array of points I'm getting from CloudMade is array of location coordinates. So is it OK that the CGPath I'm creating will contain those coordinates as points? or do i need to convert them to some screen or map points?

Comment: Well, CGPath is supposed to be plotting points but they are floating point numbers so I guess that would work, just figure out what path width gives you the best results.