# Check if a coordinate is in a polyline using google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a car rally application and for that I need to detect if the current coordinates of the car are on the path (polyline) I found a [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275076/best-practice-to-find-if-a-coordinate-is-in-a-given-polyline) but it does not use Google maps. Is it possible to do using google maps API?
I know that for polygons we have the containsLocation() method but is there anything for polylines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this for google map :

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(point, polyline, distance)
```